# Selenium 4 C# Chrome DevTools

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol, selenium4

I would like to intercept the error messages from network `Fetch/XHR`. Which method should I take or how can I make a connection and intercept this information?
I know this is necessary code base:

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                devTools = driver as IDevTools;
                session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
                devToolsSession = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
                devToolsSession.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
```

I tried to create an EventHandler but unfortunately, this `requestID` of event doesn't match with `requestID` of the DevTools parameter. How should I get `requestID` and what method do I need to intercept errors which appear on the preview page of the Network

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
IDevTools devTools = driver.OriginDriver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
FetchAdapter fetchAdapter = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.DevToolsSessionDomains>().Fetch;

var enableCommandSettings = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Fetch.EnableCommandSettings();
    
var requestPattern = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Fetch.RequestPattern();
        requestPattern.RequestStage = RequestStage.Request;
        requestPattern.ResourceType = ResourceType.XHR;
    
enableCommandSettings.Patterns = new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Fetch.RequestPattern[] { requestPattern };

fetchAdapter.Enable(enableCommandSettings);
    
EventHandler<OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Fetch.RequestPausedEventArgs> requestIntercepted = (sender, e) =>
{
    Requests.Add(e.Request);
    fetchAdapter.ContinueRequest(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Fetch.ContinueRequestCommandSettings()
    {
        RequestId = e.RequestId
    });
};

fetchAdapter.RequestPaused += requestIntercepted;
```

Comment: `ResourceType`  and `Requests` are unknown. Could you give more info?

Comment: What version of selenium did you use? This solution its probably for 4.0.0.